# Scala testing Web Service Client for POST request

Tags: scala, playframework

So the Play documentation you can find [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients) gives a very simple example for a GET call without anything like auth header or parameters.

Could somebody help me figure out how to use a similar strategy for something more complex like a POST request with JSON data as body and auth header required? I can't get it to work right now.

I want to know how to test a client using ws to do it's external http requests.

Thanks

Comment: I also searched the Play repository seeking some example but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code from one of my projects which sends sms via twilio api:

```
class SmsServiceImpl @Inject()(config: Configuration, ws: WSClient) extends SmsService {

  val twilloAccountSid = config.getString("twillo.accountSid").get
  val twilloAuthToken = config.getString("twillo.authToken").get
  val smsApiUrl = config.getString("twillo.apiBaseUrl").get + "/" +twilloAccountSid+"/Messages.json"

  override def send(phone: String, message: String): Future[Unit] = {
    val data = Map(
      "To" -> Seq(phone),
      "From" ->  Seq(config.getString("twillo.fromPhone").get),
      "Body" -> Seq(message)
    )
    val response: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(smsApiUrl).withAuth(twilloAccountSid, twilloAuthToken, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).post(data)
    response.map { response =>
      response.status match {
        case 201 => Unit
        case _ => throw new SmsSendingException(s"Failed to send sms. Got https status: ${response.status}")
      }
    }
  }
```

It is POST request with authentication.

Comment: I&#39;m looking on how to test a client like this one you just provided. I updated my question to make it clearer

Comment: It's clear enough but it's not helping. My question is how I write unit tests against your send method (or any other client methods doing post requests in it using WS with auth). I already wrote my client without issues. Testing it on the other hand is not that easy.